# Is c++ delete [] applicable to primitive types

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

In C++, if I have a dynamically allocated array of primitive type, is it necessary to use delete [] to prevent memory leakage?
For example,

```
char * x = new char[100];
delete x; // is it required to call delete [] x?
struct A {
 ...
};
A *p = new A[30];
delete [] p; // delete p would cause memory leakage
```

Please comment.

Comment: "have a dynamically allocated array for primitive type" Don't. Use std::vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dynamic memory in C++.](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/)

```
pointer = new T
pointer = new T [number_of_elements]
```

The first expression is used to allocate memory to contain one single element of type `T`. The second one is used to allocate a block (an array) of elements of type `T`, where number_of_elements is an integer value representing the amount of these. For example:

```
1.  int * foo;
2.  foo = new int [5];
```

In the below statements, first statement releases the memory of a single element allocated using new, and the second one releases the memory allocated for arrays of elements using new and a size in brackets ([]).

```
1. delete pointer;
2. delete[] pointer;
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, because the language requires it.

When the array is of a scalar type, it's pretty likely that if you accidentally use `delete` instead of `delete[]` then your program will still work. But it is still undefined behaviour---the standard does not guarantee that it works, and the next version of your compiler may break your program.

Answer (score 5):

If you allocate memory via `new T[n]` , then you must delete it via `delete[]`.

Refer [Faq](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-array-built-ins) question.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the array form of the `new` operator, you have to use the the array form of the `delete` operator.

```
char * x = new char[100];
delete [] x;

char * y = new char;
delete y;
```

The forms of `new` and `delete` to be used together does not depend on the type of object begin allocated and deallocated.

If you use

```
A *p = new A[30];
delete [] p;
```

the program is subject to undefined behavior. It may cause memory leak and continue to run but it may also crash.

Answer (score 1):

The form of operator `delete` must correspond to the form of operator `new`.   So an array allocated with `AnyType *x = new AnyType[n]` must be released using `delete [] x`.    Releasing in any other way (like `delete x`) gives undefined behaviour.    For any type - primitive or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The delete [] operator simply tells the compiler to delete all elements of the array, rather than just the first element. This is true for all types, integral and non-integral.

Comment: Does it mean for primitive-types if I use delete instead of delete []. will there be memory leakage? Can you please refer to some documenttation/link ro detect this?

Comment: @Dr.DebasishJana the documentation is the c++ standard.

Comment: @Dr.DebasishJana No one can guarantee jack smurf about what will happen. That's the beauty of Undefined Behaviour. The Standard is basically saying "Doing this after we've told you not to is such a bad idea that we won't waste our time defining what will happen." Maybe you get a leak. Maybe you won't. Maybe the program will crash. Maybe it will write a random pattern of 1s and 0s over a random file. You don't know. We don't know. The behaviour is undefined.